# Javascipt copyFile throw error and continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, throw

I am looking for a way to continue program execution for fs.copyFile is error is thrown.

```
 fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    continue;
 });
```

As of now, if there is an error the app stops running. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What's wrong with doing something like this? `fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, () => {})`

Comment: Don't throw the error, just return.

Comment: The app stops running because you are throwing an error inside a callback function. And javascript callbacks are executed sometime after the calling code is executed. Handle the error inside the callback, but don't throw it, because no code you have can logically catch and handle that error.

Comment: @Kumar I would like to know what the problem is

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: @tevemadar. Ideally I would like to get an error message in a console but continue with execution after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally I would like to get an error message in a console but continue with execution after that.

I think you could just do that:

```
fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So its halting execution because you're `throwing` the error

```
fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err; // Don't throw; this will halt execution
 });
```

If you don't need to log the error then you can either pass it an empty function or if you're using `lodash` you can pass `noop` which stands for No Operation.

```
fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, () => {});
```

Or using lodash noop:

```
const noop = require('lodash/noop');

fs.copyFile(file_from, file_to, noop);
```